# Move one file at a time to another directory, extract part of filename and stop after all files moved

Tags: linux

I have n files in source directory (C:\SRCDIR)
example:

```
837_FILE
845_FILE
```

I want to move one file at a time to target directory (C:\TGTDIR)
and take first 3 characters from a filename and jump to that function in linux script.

I tried below script

```
#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname $0`
srcdir=`C:\SRCDIR`
tgtdir=`C:\TGTDIR`

837()
{
echo "this is 837 file"
}

845()
{
echo "this is 845 file"
}

filecount=$(find $srcdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.*' | wc -l)
if [ $filecount -gt 0 ] ; then

## want to loop here like, take one file at a time 
## move to target location
## take first three characters of a file and go to that function (837, 845)
## loop until end of files

fi
```

how to use for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
srcdir="/tmp/src"
tgtdir="/tmp/tgt"
refdir="/tmp/ref"

for filename in ${srcdir}/*; do
    first_3_chars=`echo $(basename ${filename}) | cut -c1-3`;
    wc -l ${refdir}/${first_3_chars}
    mv ${filename} ${tgtdir};
done
```

Test data:

```
florin@debian:/tmp$ ll src/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 florin florin 0 iul 30 21:37 280_FILE
-rw-r--r-- 1 florin florin 0 iul 30 21:37 837_FILE
-rw-r--r-- 1 florin florin 0 iul 30 21:37 845_FILE
florin@debian:/tmp$ ll tgt/
total 0
florin@debian:/tmp$ ll ref/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 florin florin 5 iul 30 21:52 280
-rw-r--r-- 1 florin florin 0 iul 30 21:38 837
-rw-r--r-- 1 florin florin 0 iul 30 21:38 845
```

Run example:

```
florin@debian:/tmp$ ./test.sh 
1 /tmp/ref/280
0 /tmp/ref/837
0 /tmp/ref/845
florin@debian:/tmp$ ll src/
total 0
florin@debian:/tmp$ ll tgt/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 florin florin 0 iul 30 21:37 280_FILE
-rw-r--r-- 1 florin florin 0 iul 30 21:37 837_FILE
-rw-r--r-- 1 florin florin 0 iul 30 21:37 845_FILE
```

Comment: thanks florin, but my question is different, but i used first_3_chars from your input. My answer is provided in this post.  I am using $filename variable defined if statement in f837 and f270 functions. Is that good practice to use like that ?

Comment: When you call `f837()` and `f270()`, you are still in the the `for` statement context and variables are visible. If you declare $filename as local in the `fxxx` functions that behavior would change. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

cd `dirname $0`
prntdir=`pwd`

f837()
{
 echo "this is 837 file $filename"
}

f270()
{
 echo "this is 270 file $filename"
}

filecount=$(find $prntdir/srcdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.*' | wc -l)

if [ $filecount -gt 0 ] ; then

        for filepath in $prntdir/srcdir/*; do
        filename=$(basename $filepath)
        echo $filename
        mv $prntdir/srcdir/$filename $prntdir/tgtdir/$filnename
        first_3_chars=\f`echo $filename | cut -c1-3`;
        $first_3_chars
        done
else
   echo "no files exist for processing"
fi
```

Comment: Is it good practice from above answer that i used $filename variable in functions f837() and f270() ?   But i defined $filename in 'for' statement and I believe the variable $filename is local to 'for' statement only. How come it is working outside of 'for' statement without any issues ?